# Update records in extjs4 grid

Tags: extjs4

I am using Extjs4 , I got 1 grid with checkboxes i need to update records selected by user.

I am getting all records selected by user 
but problem is its not updating...Code looks as follows

```
{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Save/Update',
                   iconCls : 'icon-save',
                   handler:function(){

                        //saveAndUpdate();


                        var s=grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();

                        alert(s.length);


                        if(s.length==0){

                            alert(" No Records Selecteds");
                        }else{

                            for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++){

                                var menuKey=s[i].get('menuKey');
                                var addYN=s[i].get('addYN')==true?'Y':'N';
                                var editYN=s[i].get('editYN')==true?'Y':'N';
                                var viewYN=s[i].get('viewYN')==true?'Y':'N';
                                var deleteYN=s[i].get('deleteYN')==true?'Y':'N';
                                var exportYN=s[i].get('exportYN')==true?'Y':'N';

                                    alert(menuKey+addYN+editYN+viewYN+deleteYN+exportYN);

                                    var record = Ext.create('RoleMenuLinks');

                                    record.set({
                                        roleKey:roleKey.value,
                                        menuKey:menuKey,
                                        addYN:addYN,
                                        editYN:editYN,
                                        viewYN:viewYN,
                                        deleteYN:deleteYN,
                                        exportYN:exportYN
                                     });

                                     alert("All Record Set ");

                                    tempStore.sync();

                            }



                        }
```

its not calling java controller .... ?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a record and not putting it anywhere in this code, you need to do something with it:

```
var record = Ext.create('RoleMenuLinks');

record.set({
    roleKey:roleKey.value,
    menuKey:menuKey,
    addYN:addYN,
    editYN:editYN,
    viewYN:viewYN,
    deleteYN:deleteYN,
    exportYN:exportYN
});

// do something with the record here
```

Or are you supposed to be retrieving a record and updating it?  Because this code is not doing that.